# Convert Rich text from Tinymce and use it to fill a portion of a pdf doc

Tags: php, html, fpdf, tinymce-4, html2pdf

We have an application that takes text from a form (it's ultimately a spreadsheet) and pulls it from the database and creates a pdf document. Using fdpf and everything is working well. But there is a header portion of the doc that is currently plain text posting from a `<texarea>`, and we want to upgrade that portion to rich text using tinymce. I can easily use https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf to create a nice, full doc from the text, but it's only meant to be a small portion of the doc. This heading is not the "Header", which is taken from a jpg image.

I've tried several approaches including creating a separate doc with the rich text (html) portion and attempting to merge the two, which works great if the two are separate pages, but not so well when trying position one inside another when the one is of varying sizes, shapes, lines. Another thing I've tried is using imagemagick to convert the pdf taken from the rich text portion to a jpg and then inserting the image into the other pdf. This works great unless the heading contains mostly text(as it will).Images come through well but text becomes unreadable with my lack if image manipulation prowess.

using fpdf

``````````````````````````````````
class foo extends FPDF
{
    public function fooBody ($bar) {

`````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````

$data is obj containing db entities

current lines for the heading (having to remove html rn)

```
$data->heading = preg_replace("/&nbsp;/",'',$data->heading);

$this->MultiCell(190, 3, trim(strip_tags($data->heading)), 0, 'L', 0);
```

$foo= new foo();
$foo->fooBody(bar);
add page...
output()..
etc.

wish I could just do something like below

```
 $html2pdf->writeHTML($data34->heading);

 $richTextHeading = $html2pdf->output('file.pdf', 'S');

 foo->MultiCell(190, 3,$richTextHeading, 0, 'L', 0);
```

I want to use the same doc I have now with fpdf but somehow include some converted html for a small portion of it, but am currently only capable of having one (current doc) or the other (html doc).

Comment: If you want to use FPDF, you will ultimately need to use a HTML parser and handle every tag by yourself and style your cells according to the tags.

Comment: You may be able to use this: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this thread,  I ended up just using TCPDF, and re-writing my old code to work with TCPDF. Suprisingly I only need to change font names in a few places (Ariel->helvetica) and explicitly state cell height and margins. The old code worked mostly as is,  and this

```
   $this->MultiCell(190, 3, trim(strip_tags($data->heading)), 0, 'L', 0);
```

Is now simply this

```
   $this->writeHTML( $data->heading);
```

Comment: Here is the link to TCPDF https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf